# Mayer-Vietoris for contractible intersections

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given a countable union of spaces $$X=\bigcup_n Y_n$$
such that all intersections $$\bigcap_{i\in I}Y_i, \vert I\vert\ge 2$$
are contractible (or weaker just have trivial homology).

Is it true that in homology (in degrees $*\ge 2$)
$$H_*(X)=\bigoplus_n H_*(Y_n)$$
is the direct sum?

Comment: Why don't you allow $* = 1$?

Comment: Because a circle is a union of 3 intervals with contractible intersections.

Comment: The intersection of all three intervals is empty.

Comment: Or do you allow also empty intersections?

Comment: You are right. *=1 should be okay. I do not want empty intersections, so the example is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The infinite earring space should be a counterexample: with the usual description as a union of a family of circles of decreasing radii, the intersection of any set of those circles is a point and hence contractible, but the homology of the whole space is larger than the direct sum. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) gives a description.

There are higher dimensional analogues which are also counterexamples: see the paper by Barratt and Milnor, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/.

Comment: If you take $Y_n$ to be the circles constituting the Hawaiian earring, then arbitrary intersections are the one-point space where the circles meet.

Comment: Right, I realized this too and was just coming to fix it.